# Assign classes to each term of a custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I would ask how can I assign classes to each term of a custom taxonomy.
I have created custom taxonomies with CPT UI plugin (WordPress) and I display these with this code:

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'color' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
$term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'color' );
if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
continue;
echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
}
?>
```

Now, I would style with css each term, but I need to assign a different class for each taxonomy term.

Thank you

Comment: Yes its'use key in foreach and also in anchor tag echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '" class="some.$key.">' . $term->name . '</a>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use key in foreach and add `$key` in class name. It always will return new class, like `someclass_0, someclass_1`:

```
foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
   $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'color' );
   if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
     continue;
   echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '" class="someclass_'.$key.'">' . $term->name . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Samvel for editing if answer is correct then give me upvote plz

Comment: how the both class same it always return new class like someclass_0, someclass_1 . please explain how same

Comment: Hi Anand, if you go to https://flowersliving.com/2018_v2/a-florence-wedding-so-pretty-youd-swear-it-was-a-styled-shoot/ you can see inside the post title block (pink background box) 4 rows with 2 categories (Senape and Viola).
The fourth and last row is made with your suggested code.
If you inspect Senape and Viola, you'll see that the class is the same for both...

Comment: Anand, this is perfect!

Comment: Hi Anand, your code is perfect, but if I create another post with different colors, it takes the same classes 'some class_0', 'some class_1', 'some class_2', etc. So, if I have 3 colors (red, green, blue) on the first post and different 3 colors (yellow, pink, purple) on the second post, I have the same classes and I cannot styling properly.
Any idea on how to fix it?